# How to encrypt files so that root cannot view them?

Tags: linux, unix, encryption

I have a powerful linux server with lots of CPU+RAM which sits around idle 99% of the day.

I have a friend who has some financial models that he runs on his laptop for 2 hours a day.

I want to invite him to use my server, but he doesn't want me to see his models, code, etc.

Is there a simple way to encrypt things so only he can see them?  Some sort of encrypted folder perhaps?  Or allow him to mount an external filesystem?

Comment: Create a VM and run it as a virtual server.  That way he has full conrol of it.  If you stop being friends, he can move the virtual server off your machine to somewhere else.

Comment: @cup Thanks for your comment but I don't understand how that works, where is the VM storage ?

Comment: When you create a VM, it uses up some space on your disk.  It also uses your CPU.  Since the VM is entirely under his control - he can set the passwords etc.  Just remote into the VM and he's away, you don't need to know anything about it other than how much disk and how many processors it is using.  All you are offering is the resource.  He has full control over everything else.

Comment: But I could access his files by opening the VM files, could I not ?

Comment: @CaptainCodeman - Encrypt the file system within the VM. One can also use a VeraCrypt container. Of course to run the models the container would have to be mounted.  So the VM likely would be a better solution.

Comment: Would it be acceptable do only have protection at-rest, i.e. would it be okay that the data and code would be readable during the two hours the computation runs?

Comment: It will  be stored as a disk image.  You could access it but it would take you some time to reassemble it  to something you could use.  It will be a mix of os, programs, data , unused disk areas and deleted files. Many of these could be fragmented